# CloudFormation mentions Document type is required for schema version 2.2

Tags: yaml, aws-cloudformation, amazon-systems-manager, aws-ssm

The following error is displayed on the stack in the cloudformation service of the browser AWS console.

> Document type is required for schema version 2.2 (Service: AmazonSSM; Status Code: 400; Error Code: InvalidDocumentSchemaVersion; Request ID: xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx)

It occurred for the following Resource in the CloudFormation Document:

```
InstanceConfigDocument:
  Type: AWS::SSM::Document
  Properties:
    Content:
      schemaVersion: "2.2"
      description: Join Active Directory
      mainSteps:
        - action: aws:domainJoin
          name: joiningDomain
          inputs:
            directoryId: !Ref ActiveDirectory
            directoryName: myDirectoryName
            dnsIpAddresses:
              - !Select ['0', !GetAtt 'ActiveDirectory.DnsIpAddresses']
              - !Select ['1', !GetAtt 'ActiveDirectory.DnsIpAddresses']
```

How can I solve this error?

Answer (score 0):

Adding the `DocumentType` property worked for me.

```
  InstanceConfigDocument:
    Type: AWS::SSM::Document
    Properties:
      DocumentType: "Command"
      Content:
        schemaVersion: "2.2"
        description: Join Active Directory
        mainSteps:
          - action: aws:domainJoin
            name: joiningDomain
            inputs:
              directoryId: !Ref ActiveDirectory
              directoryName: myDirectoryName
              dnsIpAddresses:
                - !Select ['0', !GetAtt 'ActiveDirectory.DnsIpAddresses']
                - !Select ['1', !GetAtt 'ActiveDirectory.DnsIpAddresses']
```

The [CloudFormation Documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-ssm-document.html) refers to `DocumentType` as not required. It seems it is required for SSM Documents using schema version 2.2.

Comment: There is no "Properties" property in version 2.2 "Unknown property error" in CDK but yes, it is required and there is no documentation on the schema for the "DocumentType" property when deploying programmatically with cdk. 

Any pointers?

Comment: sorry I don't have a lot of experience with the CDK. I assume that you do not have to specify the "Properties" property. In this example only DocumentType and Content are properties. I would assume that the CDK is smart enough that you do not have to add Properties as well...

Comment: Thank you for replying but right after I posted this question, I managed to figure out how to include the property in the schema for the stack. 

Since the output json schema doesn't feature the document type in the cloudformation stack content and it doesn't mention in the aws docs that the property is required, I had this question. 

It is resolved now, thanks again because quite possibly, reading this thread helped clear my mind!:)